# Get notified when Private DNS changes on Android Pie

Tags: android

In Android P we have the ability to set a Private DNS in system/device settings.

My Service currently uses VPN so I am required to honour the Private DNS setting.

**How do I get notified when the Private DNS changes?**

I am already checking the setting before I establish my connection (with my own DNS), but once my VPN is up and running I want to react if the user changes their Private DNS Setting, however I can't find it documented anywhere.

My existing connectivity action receiver is not notified by changes

```
registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments in the sources JavaDoc I managed to find a working solution

```
ConnectivityManager cMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (cMgr != null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        cMgr.registerNetworkCallback(new NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network network, LinkProperties linkProperties) {
                super.onLinkPropertiesChanged(network, linkProperties);
                L.d(TAG, "onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network = " + network + ", LinkProperties = " + linkProperties + ")");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    L.i(TAG, "LinkProperties.isPrivateDnsActive = " + linkProperties.isPrivateDnsActive() + ", server =" + linkProperties.getPrivateDnsServerName());
             }
        }
    });
}
```